# HttpWebRequest StreamReader fails with utf-8 is not a supported encoding name error

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, streamreader

I'm using following code to retrieve data from web pages. It works great in most pages, but throws error in some pages as below;

```
    String url = @"https://m.facebook.com";
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;
            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            else
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
    // utf-8 is not a supported encoding name error
    }
```

How to fix this? Other posts here did not solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here is that `response.CharacterSet` is returning `"utf-8"`. The method `Encoding.GetEncoding` has no idea what that means because the of the quotes around the text. So you have to strip those out.

Replace this line:

```
readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, 
    Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
```

with this one:

```
readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, 
    Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet.Replace("\"", string.Empty)));
```

Comment: Thanks Andy it worked and gave me the html source, but however html content is slightly different than the source I get from chrome browser>.view page source. any idea?

Comment: @nawala that's the other question. Guessing that you're comparing code from Inspector that was changed by JS scripts with plain downloaded source. Note that after page was loaded, JS can change it significantly.